# Grouping rows by column value/category in a Google pie chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
sub_note | item_amount | sub_cat       |
---------------------------------------|
Spotify  |  $5.99      | entertainment |
Vodafone |  $35        | phone         |
Netflix  |  $5.99      | entertainment |
```

I want to display a Google pie chart that tells me how much is being spent per category i.e. Entertainment, Phone etc.

I have used the following adaptation of the Google Quick Start example, but all I'm seeing is a blank chart with 'No data'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
    data.addRows([
     <?php 
     $query = "SELECT SUM(sub_amount) AS sub_cat, subs_total FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id ='".$user_id."' GROUP BY sub_cat ORDER BY sub_cat";
      $exec = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
      echo "['".$row['sub_cat']."',".$row['subs_total']."],";
      }
 ?>]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Spending by Category',
                   'width':600,
                   'height':400};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

It's clear that there's something wrong with the query code and how it's being grouped, but I'm scratching my head trying to figure this out.

Any pointers would be great!

UPDATE: Thanks to @WhiteHat for the SQL correction, here's the functioning code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
    data.addRows([
     <?php 
     $query = "SELECT sub_cat, SUM(sub_amount) as subs_total FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id ='".$user_id."' GROUP BY sub_cat ORDER BY sub_cat";
      $exec = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
      echo "['".$row['sub_cat']."',".$row['subs_total']."],";
      }
   ?>]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':600,
                   'height':400};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No, they're the same. I changed that after I posted this topic, so I've updated the code above to reflect the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sql...

`$query = "SELECT sub_cat, SUM(sub_amount) as subs_total FROM subscriptions WHERE sub_user_id ='".$user_id."' GROUP BY sub_cat ORDER BY sub_cat";`

The category should be the first column and subtotal second.

Comment: I added your SQL, and it worked perfectly, thank you!
Edit: Also, no, I wasn't receiving any errors on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you test if your sql code return something? 
I would help you if you give to me the correct dataset in your SQL.
Try to do an `echo` or `vardump` outside your javascript to know if your SQL is Good.